# Regex with dynamic keys in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have an object, and inside my HTML I use tags of the form `[itemkey]` to refer to the value of the `itemkey` property of that object, and want to replace these tags with their values. My JavaScript code looks like this:

```
_.forEach(objectItem,function(val,key){
  var re = new RegExp('\[' + key +'\]','g');
  htmlDump = htmlDump.replace(re,val)
});
```

But it does not work. What is wrong?

Comment: You need to double escape the special characters in `RegExp` constructor. Use `new RegExp('\\[' + key + '\\]');`

Comment: I tried It, but did not works again.

Comment: Does `key` contain any special characters?

Comment: Why not just `new RegExp(key);`

Comment: I guess, the issue is with the value of variable `htmlDump` being replaced in the next iteration.

Comment: I use it to replace html. Text coul contain some words as key's name.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99049/discussion-between-tushar-and-kamuran-sonecek).

Comment: thanks @Tushar for your advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whatever manipulation of the HTML you do, nothing you do will have any effect until you replace the HTML of the document.

Other than that, there is no logical reason why @Tushar's approach as given in the first comment would not work (except that it needed a `g` flag):

```
new RegExp('\\[' + key + '\\]', 'g');
```

Overall, this approach is flawed. You are replacing the entire HTML; for instance, that will wipe out all event listeners. Instead, you should iterate through the DOM and apply your transformation to each text node.

Please be aware that ideally you should be escaping the `key` in order to avoid regexp-related characters in it from breaking the regexp.